# what do you call a person who does everything for wealth or only cares about being wealthy

Tags: single-word-requests

I am trying to describe a Shakespeare character. I need a word for a person who does everything for wealth or who only cares about being wealthy.

**How would I use the word I need in a sentence?**  This person is (*insert the word here*)

Comment: Psychologically they would probably be a psychopath/sociopath, but those terms do not necessarily imply desire for wealth -- it can be power, fame, etc.

Comment: "Kleptocrat" generally refers to a ruler who is in it for the money, but I just noted that *The New Yorker* uses it in a somewhat broader sense.

Comment: [Materialistic](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/materialistic)

Answer (score 4):

You seem to be looking for a noun!

How about, *moneygrubber*?

A definition of *moneygrubber* is "a person who is aggressively engaged in or preoccupied with making or saving money." (Dictionary.com)

So, in your example sentence.  "This person is a *moneygrubber*."

You could also try *Scrooge* as an allusion to the Dickens character. As in,

"The guy was a real *Scrooge*!

Which is a really fun sentence, in my opinion!  But, if you are talking about Shakespeare and you bring up Dickens, you may be opening up a whole "nother" can of worms...

Comment: There's a real semantic gulf between ***to grub*** *(root, search for something in the earth, etc.)* and ***to grab*** *(seize suddenly and eagerly; hence, to appropriate to oneself in a rapacious or unscrupulous manner)*. Comparing BrE and AmE corpuses for the more common *hyphenated* forms [money-grubbing,money-grabbing](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=money-grubbing%2Cmoney-grabbing&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmoney%20-%20grubbing%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmoney%20-%20grabbing%3B%2Cc0) it seems Brits are moving more to the latter.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Yes, as a Brit, I would say 'moneygrabbing'.

Comment: Sounds like you're on to something, @fumblefingers! I'm an American, and I've never heard "moneygrabbing" used, although I can certainly grok the meaning of it. "Moneygrubbing" and "moneygrubber" I've heard lots of times.

Comment: Yeah, in the US "money  grabbing" would not have nearly the pejorative meaning that "moneygrubbing" has.

Comment: I originally assumed ***grubstake*** would have been predominantly a C19 US term (in my mind it's strongly associated with "Wild West" prospectors, "dirt farmers", etc.). But [this NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=grubstake&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cgrubstake%3B%2Cc0) suggests to me it was probably more of a regional / dialectal usage that gained wider traction during the "linguistic melting pots" of WW1 and WW2. It's 4-5 times less common in BrE than AmE, presumably because the *referents* are/were less common in the UK.

Answer (score 2):

[Avaricious](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/avaricious) or one of its synonyms.

> *Avaricious, covetous, greedy, rapacious* share the sense of desiring to possess more of something than one already has or might in normal circumstances be entitled to.
>    **Avaricious** often implies a pathological, driven greediness for money or other valuables and usually suggests a concomitant miserliness: the cheerless dwelling of an avaricious usurer.
>   **Covetous** implies a powerful and usually illicit desire for the property or possessions of another: The book collector was openly covetous of my rare first edition.
>    **Greedy**, the most general of these terms, suggests a naked and uncontrolled desire for almost anything—food and drink, money, emotional gratification: embarrassingly greedy for praise.
>    **Rapacious**, stronger and more assertive than the other terms, implies an aggressive, predatory, insatiable, and unprincipled desire for possessions and power: a rapacious frequenter of tax sales and forced auctions.
>   <sub>*from [dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/avaricious)'s "synonym study" under 'avaricious'*</sub>

Answer (score 1):

'Covetous' would describe someone who envies what others have, 'miserly' describes the unnatural pleasure in money once gained, but
***acquisitive*** describes just the desire to possess, itself.

> **Acquisitive** : strongly desirous of acquiring and possessing

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/acquisitive)

> We can become quite **acquisitive**; we need the latest in everything. We might begin to think that fast cars, fashionable clothes, or the latest software will make us happy.

---

> 1955   A. M. Lindbergh Gift from Sea vii. 114   The **acquisitive** instinct is incompatible with true appreciation of beauty.
>
> 1998   Independent 6 June i. 28/4   Smackheads tend to involve themselves in what the police call ‘**acquisitive** crimes’—shoplifting, burglary and car theft.

[OED-3](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/1741?redirectedFrom=acquisitive#eid) (Requires subscription)

Answer (score 1):

[Mercenary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/mercenary) refers to interest in money specifically, rather than general acquisitiveness; I am not sure if this is really what you want, but you say so.

Answer (score -1):

Capitalist - a more modern word with American implications.

Plutocrat - a bit more abstract with political overtones.

Bourgeois - has class struggle implications.